# NodeJs - How to get Windows ProgramData directory in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, windows, application-data, windows-users, programdata

I need to write some files into folder, that can be access any local user and can be modified by any user.
So I decided to use Windows `ProgramData` folder. I found following details from a [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/278562/what-is-the-programdata-folder-in-windows/).

> There’s also the ProgramData folder. This folder has most in common
> with the Application Data folders, but—instead of having an individual
> folder for each user—the ProgramData folder is shared among all the
> user accounts on your PC.
>
> On Windows XP, there was no C:\ProgramData folder. Instead, there was
> a “C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data” folder.
> Starting with Windows Vista, the All Users application data folder was
> moved to C:\ProgramData.
>
> You can still see this today. If you plug C:\Users\All Users\ into
> File Explorer or Windows Explorer on Windows 10, Windows will
> automatically redirect you to the C:\Program Data folder. It’ll
> redirect any program that tries to write to C:\Users\All Users\ to the
> C:\ProgramData folder, too.

Is there any method to get Windows `ProgramData` directory in NodeJs, without hard coding like `"C:\ProgramData"` or `"C:\Users\All Users\"` ?

Comment: According to two answers both process.env.ProgramData and process.env.ALLUSERSPROFILE give ProgramData folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-process-env-property/) article can help you.

It solves the problem by using the process.env property:

> The process.env property is an inbuilt application programming interface of the process module which is used to get the user environment.

You should get "C:\ProgramData" from "ALLUSERPROFILE" as follows:

```
// Include process module 
const process = require('process'); 
// Printing process.env property value 
var env = process.env; 
console.log("alluserprofile: " + env.ALLUSERSPROFILE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the environment variable `PROGRAMDATA`. See

```
console.log(process.env.PROGRAMDATA);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its available as environment variable in windows.You can access system/user level environment variables using process.env. So Simplest answer is

> process.env.PROGRAMDATA

Windows sometimes changes these variables in major windows upgrades.
you can always verify it here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables